# Windows task Manager shows wrong memory?

Tags: windows-xp, windows-server-2003, task-manager

Guess what it the memory on my system from below?

[image]

It is 3GB but it show 4.8? Why

On my different computer, it is running Windows Server 2003, it has 2 GB installed but it show 4GB (Limit field).

Can someone explain that, what does Limit mean. The available address space or total memory on system?

Comment: Total Physical Memory: `3134356 KB` Where do you get `4.8 GB` from?

Comment: True I was reading the wrong value. I usually go by the bar and got confused.

Comment: @Dave: What bar? I don't see any graphs labeled memory. . .

Comment: Just above 1.48 GB. I thought this represented the actual memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [commit limit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commit_charge) can exceed physical memory. The commit limit is the maximum amount of pagefile backed virtual memory that could be consumed without any new virtual memory being allocated. It's how much pagefile+RAM the system could need, maximum, without any new specific allocation requests.